# AVERAGEX Confusion

Tags: dax

In my data model I have a table named 'Online Sales' and a Dates table (daily dates from 2005 to 2010). They are joined M:1.

I am attempting to use AVERAGEX in the following ways. The first approach grossly inflates my daily average when placed in a matrix containing a filter context of year and month. The second approach generates correct results. I don't understand why they both don't produce the same results.

## 1

```
Average Sales By Day =
AVERAGEX(
  'Dates',
   [Sales Amount Online]
)
```

## 2

```
Average Sales By Day =
AVERAGEX(
   'Online Sales'
   [Sales Amount Online]
)
```

[Sales Amount Online] is a measure as follows:

```
Sales Amount Online = SUMX(
   'Online Sales',
   'Online Sales'[Sales Quantity] * 'Online Sales'[Unit Price] - 'Online Sales'[Discount Amount]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first measure, you are iterating through each row in the `'Dates'` table and calculating `[Sales Amount Online]` for each day (assuming daily level granularity).

When you evaluate the `[Sales Amount Online]` measure with a day as your filter context, you get the sum of all sales that occur on that day (which could be many).

In the second measure, you are iterating through each row in the `'Online Sales'` table and calculating `[Sales Amount Online]` for each transaction (assuming that's what each row represents).

When you evaluate `[Sales Amount Online]` measure within `'Online Sales'` row context, the measure only sums sales from that single row (assuming all rows are unique).

---

Basically, #1 is average per day and #2 is average per transaction (provided my assumptions are correct).

Comment: Ah! I see. With the first approach, I'm actually only calculating a single value for each day, which is the sum of all sales for the day. And the average will be the same as the sum since there is only a single value. The granularity is at the day level. With the second approach the granularity is at the transaction level. DAX can be very subtle!